# Citando conteudo em ingles

Tags: debate

Notei que as vezes o pessoal cita sites com respostas em inglês, como [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6027/possivel-realizar-rolagem-no-git-bash). Nesse caso, o texto fica em inglês e pode não ser entendido por usuários que falam somente português. E consigo imaginar que, muitas vezes, a citação seja o cerne da resposta. O que devemos fazer com esses casos?

Answer (score 4):

Acho que uma vez que a citação original em inglês seja feita, o autor da resposta deve adicionar também uma tradução do original, para assim efetivamente responder a pergunta na linguagem esperada.

Muitas das perguntas que faremos no estourodepilha terão uma resposta em inglês na internet. No caso de citar a fonte e não traduzir, logo logo teremos muitas respostas aceitas em inglês, o que foge totalmente da idéia do site.

Acho que a tradução de citações em inglês deve ser obrigatória, com pressão da comunidade, assim como há para respostas só com links. Isso é, devemos evitar votar a favor de perguntas que tenham uma resposta em inglês sem tradução, e até mesmo votar contra de acordo com o julgamento pessoal em relação a resposta.

Existem outros meios de lidar com a tradução, como @FelipeAvelar comentou. Um deles é sinalizar para os moderadores, mas não acho que os moderadores possam tomar alguma atitude positiva nesse caso.

Outra alternativa seria editar o post com a tradução. O problem que eu vejo nessa alternative é dar credibilidade (através de upvotes) para uma pessoa que não escreveu em portugues no SO-pt. No caso de se passar muito tempo e a pessoa não traduzir a citação, vale a pena responder denovo com a citação traduzida, evitando assim a credibilidade injusta para o usuário que respondeu indevidamente e, ao mesmo tempo, evitando danos para o conteúdo do estourodepilha.

Comment: O que levanta outro ponto, caso o autor não traduza, o que deve ser feito? A pergunta deverá ser sinalizada? Ou alguém editará fazendo a tradução?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Eu iria responder no comentário, mas achei que valia mais a pena editar meu post porque é uma resposta consideravelmente grande